# Terraform AWS: How to output subnets per AZ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to output subnets per AZ. I tried many different approaches. I am able to output route tables per AZ. As follows are the output of route tables per AZ.

```
private_route_tables = {
  "us-west-2a" = "rtb-0443231b6########"
  "us-west-2b" = "rtb-05a1de447########"
  "us-west-2c" = "rtb-0e8e68db6########"
}
```

As follows are the output of public subnets:

```
public_subnet_ids_per_az = [
  tolist([
    "subnet-0159b3273########",
    "subnet-06e6f50e1########",
  ]),
  tolist([
    "subnet-030d84387########",
    "subnet-04a46deb6########",
  ]),
  tolist([
    "subnet-086f2527f########",
    "subnet-06649e7ef########",
  ]),
  tolist([]),
]
```

I would like to output public subnets per AZ, something like the following:

```
public_subnet_ids_per_az = {
   "us-west-2a" =  ["subnet-0159b3273########", "subnet-06e6f50e1########"]
   "us-west-2b" =  ["subnet-030d84387########", "subnet-04a46deb6########"]
   "us-west-2c" =  ["subnet-086f2527f########", "subnet-06649e7ef########"]
}
```

There are four AZs in us-west-2. I only want to use three of them. I tired many different ways. I either got syntax errors, or I cannot output the above output. As follows are my code.

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

terraform {
  # The configuration for this backend will be filled in by Terragrunt
  backend "s3" {}
}

#
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {

  tags = {
    EKS           = var.cluster_name
    ProvisionedBy = "Terraform"
    Environment   = var.environment
  }

  number_azs = var.number_azs

  azs = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, local.number_azs)
  subnets = [for cidr_block in cidrsubnets(var.cidr, 4, 4, 4) : cidrsubnets(cidr_block, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)]
  private_subnets = local.subnets[0]
  database_subnets = local.subnets[1]
  public_subnets = local.subnets[2]

  private_route_tables = zipmap(local.azs, module.vpc.private_route_table_ids)
  public_subnet_ids_az = [for k, v in data.aws_subnets.public_per_az : v.ids]

}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "5.0.0"

  cidr                                            = var.cidr
  name                                            = "vpc-${var.cluster_name}"
  azs                                             = local.azs
  private_subnets                                 = local.private_subnets
  public_subnets                                  = local.public_subnets
  enable_nat_gateway                              = true
  single_nat_gateway                              = false
  one_nat_gateway_per_az                          = true

  enable_dns_hostnames                            = true
  enable_dns_support                              = true

  tags                                            = local.tags

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "subnet"                                       = "public"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "subnet"                                       = "private"
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "public_per_az" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids)

  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [module.vpc.vpc_id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:subnet"
    values = ["public"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone-id"
    values = ["${each.value}"]
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  description = "Region for the VPC"
  default     = "us-west-2"
}

variable "cluster_name" {
  type = string
  default = "eks-test"
}

variable "environment" {
  default = "test"
}

variable "cidr" {
  default = "10.2.0.0/16"
}

variable "number_azs" {
  type        = number
  description = "Number of Availability Zones to create resources in the VPC."
  default     = 3

  validation {
    condition     = var.number_azs > 0 && var.number_azs < 4
    error_message = "The number of AZs to configure has to be between 1 - 3."
  }
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "The ID of the VPC"
  value       = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

output "azs" {
  description = "A list of availability zones specified as argument"
  value       = local.azs
}

# Subnets

output "public_subnet_ids_per_az" {
  description = "List of IDs of public subnets"
  value       = local.public_subnet_ids_az
}

output "private_route_tables" {
  description = "Map from a list of AZs and a corresponding list of private_route_table_ids"
  value       = local.private_route_tables
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do change the data source and `public_subnet_ids_az` into:

```
data "aws_subnets" "public_per_az" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)

  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [module.vpc.vpc_id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:subnet"
    values = ["public"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone"
    values = ["${each.value}"]
  }
}

locals {
  public_subnet_ids_az = {for k, v in data.aws_subnets.public_per_az : tolist(v.filter)[0].values[0] => v.ids if length(v.ids) > 0}
}
```

Example output for `us-east-1`:

```
public_subnet_ids_per_az = {
  "us-east-1a" = tolist([
    "subnet-04de7df31d8784914",
    "subnet-0f8f2b41980917679",
  ])
  "us-east-1b" = tolist([
    "subnet-086bcdf27617ef60f",
    "subnet-06c34ca8d5f74c53e",
  ])
  "us-east-1c" = tolist([
    "subnet-05b38a0680fb561a3",
    "subnet-0fa83c04e2a4882c5",
  ])
}
```